# MySQL transactions

Tags: mysql, transactions

I'm currently creating a messaging system and I was wondering if I should be using transactions (from what I understand their purpose is).

I currently have three tables:

**conversations** : subject, etc
**messages** : messages (FK constraint to conversations table)
**participants** : user ids of people in conversation

Lets say that an user has to be a participant of a conversation to read it. In a page, I'd perform two queries, one for the conversation data and one for the messages. It could be me being paranoid but how can I ensure that an users participation (the overall state of things) doesn't change between these two queries? Would a transaction be the key? Would I encounter any performance problems?

(participation is checked via join on both queries)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Transactions should certainly help in your situation. You might need some extra help from the database constraints hough.

Comment: Thanks mate. I currently have a constraint so that a message and a participant cannot exist without a conversation but I'm guessing I'd need the transaction to guarantee the user's participation being constant throughout the queries.

Answer (score 0):

If you're worried that a person could leave the conversation (through a separate process or request) between your two queries then a transaction isn't what you want. What you want to do is add a join to the "conversations" table to filter out people that are no longer in the conversation, something sort of like this:

```
select stuff
from messages m
join conversations c on (m.conversation = c.id and c.person = $current_user)
where ...
```

Where `$current_user` is the user in question. Then, if `$current_user` is no longer in the conversation, no rows will come out of the join and nothing will be selected.

Comment: I have a participation table join on both the conversation query (returns 1 row) and messages query (returns n rows) so that they only return with participation - bu how could I prevent that participation doesn't change between queries?

Comment: @RS7: Then, AFAIK, a transaction with an [isolation level](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-transaction.html) of "repeatable read" should work.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you something like Mu is suggesting? Just add a little twist...

```
select m.*
from messages m
join conversations c on (m.conversation = c.id)
join participation p on (p.conversation = c.id) 
where p.person = $current_user
and...
```

Am I missing something?
Transactions are usually used to ensure consistency between records on writing operations, not reading.